# I can't authenticate users in moodle using Ldap

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, moodle

I just installed Moodle on a Windows server and I wanted to use Ldap to authenticate users. Under Site Administration -> plugins -> authentication -> Ldap Server, I have set the Host Url which is equal to my AD server (ie 111.111.111.111), Version : 3, use LTS : No, Ldap Encoding : utf-8 and on bind setting (Distinguishing Name) I have set `cn=myUser,dc=domain,dc=co,dc=tz` since my email is `myUser@domain.co.tz` and the password corresponding to that user.

When I try to authenticate a user, I get this error:

> LDAP-module cannot connect to any servers: Server: 'AD IP', Bind result: ''

Comment: Have you test the settings? Go to site admin > plugins > authentication > manage authentication > scroll down to LDAP and click "Test settings"

Comment: @RussellEngland Thanks for the response, turn out the DN was wrong. Now Connecting to your LDAP server was successful but i atill cant authenticate i get the error Invalid login, please try again

Comment: Can you turn on debugging to developer level, try to log in, then copy and paste the error into the question - site admin > development > debugging > debug messages = developer and Display debug messages = checked

Comment: @RussellEngland Thanks again for the reply 
i get a couple of warnings which i dont believe they are the cause if the issue 

See Below
Warning: Undefined array key 0 in C:\server\moodle\lib\outputrenderers.php on line 1563

Deprecated: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($search) of type array|string is deprecated in C:\server\moodle\lib\outputrenderers.php on line 1564

Answer (score 1):

From the given description, the code tries to connect without TLS, LDAPv3 protocol.
It seems that :

-Either the authentication protocols do not match

OR

-The username and password that gets an invalid login error has 'password change required at next logon' attribute set_ in this case unchecking this setting will be needed.

For the authentication protocol mismatch please check the Security Event Logs on the domain controller that the code connects. That DC might have provided a referral DC, you may check via netstat, in that case Security Event Logs on the referral DC should also be examined.

If the code tries to connect with a simple bind w/ cleartext credential, this might be rejected. You may check this via choosing LDAPS:// instead of LDAP in your LDAP settings and try the test again. DC should have SSL certificate and port 636 on the DC should be open.

It the code tries to connect using NTLM v1 the Domain Controller might have prohibited old version NTLM.

I did not see a Kerberos description, so I assume Kerberos is not used in the scenario.